# c++: error: cannot convert ‘ns3::TracedValue<ns3::SequenceNumber<unsigned int, int> >’ to ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}

Tags: c++, casting, ns-3

I am trying to cast `TracedValue<uint32_t>  m_bytesInFlight` to **uint32_t** but I get the following error

```
 error: cannot convert ‘ns3::TracedValue<ns3::SequenceNumber<unsigned int, int> >’ to ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}
```

Function prototype and variable declarations are

```
uint32_t UnAckDCount (void) const;

TracedValue<uint32_t>  m_bytesInFlight {0};        //!< Bytes in flight
```

Here i am calling the function

```
uint32_t 
TcpSocketBase::UnAckDCount () const
{
  return m_tcb->m_highTxMark - (uint32_t) m_tcb->m_bytesInFlight;
}
```

Please suggest some method so that I can execute the return statement to get the result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `m_tcb->m_highTxMark` to `m_tcb->m_highTxMark.Get().GetValue()`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @DineshKhandelwal Yes it magically worked. How did it solve my problem? Will you explain it a bit in detail?

Comment: Hi, added explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `m_tcb->m_highTxMark` to `m_tcb->m_highTxMark.Get().GetValue()` should work.

Seeing the compiler error, it's easy to figure out that variable `m_highTxMark` is of type `ns3::TracedValue<ns3::SequenceNumber<unsigned int, int> >`. I checked the documentation of `ns3::TracedValue` and `ns3::SequenceNumber`, they both have getter functions Get() and GetValue() respectively.

See:

https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_traced_value.html
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_sequence_number.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.